# Eclipse plugins build issue

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

The plugin Workspace(java) that I use while working with eclipse is quite big approx 250MB. Everytime I open a fresh eclipse session with the Workspace, it gives me errors. However reloading the target platform plugins just solves the problem.

When most of the projects are closed & eclipse restarted the error that is described above & the projects which show errors previously are not there & the code runs fine.

I am keen to know, what does a reload do different & want to make it possible to open the workspace without any errors.

Comment: What errors? You forgot to actually tell us what they are. What is the target platform both before and after reloading?

Comment: The target is same before & after the reload. There are multiple errors a few I can mention though. 

Plug-in: org.eclipse.pde.core
Message: Invalid manifest header Export-Package: ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using eclipse oxygen solved the issue. The workspace is loaded directly without any error as was with eclipse mars.